# Convert Dictionary(ExpandoObject) to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, expandoobject

I'm currently trying to convert an expandoobject to datatable. What would be the way to do this? So far i have my own PsqlRequest class which is responsible for executing the query and also returning the results from the executed query.

```
PsqlRequest psqlRequest = new PsqlRequest("select * from table");
var psqlResponse = psqlRequest.ExecuteQuery();
```

psqlResponse would return results in form of an expandoobject. Looks something like this:

```
[id, 0], [status, 21], [code, 123456789], [date, 2020-01-01], [is_active, True], [confirm_state, 1]
[id, 1], [status, 21], [code, 343434343], [date, 2020-01-02], [is_active, False], [confirm_state, 2]
[id, 2], [status, 33], [code,], [date, 2020-01-04], [is_active, True], [confirm_state, 1]
```

How should i go about this?

Comment: So what bit are you stuck on - getting the data from the query ? Parsing the results ? Populating the data table ?

Comment: @auburg parsing the results from expandoobject and populating the datatable

Comment: So what's proving difficult - you can use syntax like psqlResponse["id"] to get at the data. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8 on how to populate a DataTable

Comment: @auburg i should get the keys from my dictionary and set them as column names in my DataTable, then populate the table with values from the same dictionary. Right now i'm stuck on getting the keys.

Comment: Which properties are the keys in your expandoobject ?

Comment: @auburg id, status, code, date, is_active, confirm_state

Comment: So i'm assuming you're able to get at the key values like so:  psqlResponse["id"], psqlResponse["status"] etc ? Then have you looked at the link i sent above which explains how to create a DataTable with columns using those values from your object ? You need to explain further in your question what you've tried and doesn't work.